# Как сгенерировать cлучайное число в шестнадцатеричном формате

Tags: php, числа

Подскажите как на PHP сгенерировать cлучайное число в шестнадцатеричном формате длинной от 16  символов.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, минимальное шестнадцатеричное число из 16  символов (если учитывать, что старший разряд не равен нулю) - это 0x1000000000000000. То есть 1 152 921 504 606 847 000 (1 квинтиллион 152 квадриллиона 921 триллион 504 миллиарда 606 миллионов 847 тысяч)

Исключительно из любопытства - что вы собрались делать с такими числами? Пересчитывать атомы во вселенной?

Comment: предлагаю генерить в лоб, посимвольно )

Comment: можно еще поморочиться с gmp_random :) и потом лишнии отрезать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю несколько вариантов:

1. `substr(md5(rand(1,9999).microtime()), 0, 16);`
2. генерим число, 4 раза по 4 символа

`$num = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
         $first = 0;
         if ($i == 0) {
             $first = 0x1000;
         }
         $num .= dechex(rand($first, 0xffff));
    }`

Comment: во втором примере будут небольшие слепые зоны, т.е. к примеру `0x1000000000000000` никогда не сгенериться, т.к. каждая четверка будет рандомиться с 1000

Comment: Согласен. Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

если установлен модуль gmp (для больших чисел)

```
<?php
//генерируем число длиной от 16 до 32 hex символов. рисуем в hex, 
$min=16;
$maxlen=32;
$r=gmp_add(gmp_random(ceil($maxlen/PHP_INT_SIZE)),gmp_pow(16,$min));
$out=str_pad(strtoupper(substr(gmp_strval($r,16),1,$min+rand(0,$maxlen-$min))),$maxlen,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo "0x"."$out\n"
```

не то чтобы это хороший способ, просто стало интересно так реализовать :)

http://ideone.com/n5zGL6